# Is there a way to make land classifications with simple RGB satellite images?

Tags: cartography, land-classification

The area of interest I am working on mapping is quite small, just under 10 acres. I need to create simple landcover vectors (trees, low vegetation/grass, water). I don't have access to high enough resolution remote sensing data for such a small area. I was wondering if creating such a classification would be possible using something as simple as a google satellite image or something similar. It only needs to be accurate enough for visual symbology, not any statistical analysis.

I've done this before with Landsat images on a much larger study site using supervised classification. In this case supervised classification seems overly complex for the task, I also don't know how well it would work with just 3 bands.

Is there a standard way in which something like this is done for cartography using GIS? Other than just digitizing vectors over the satellite image

Answer (score 0):

A supervised classification is not that complicated but if you are still not interested in that approach you could try an unsupervised classification (here are links for [QGIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnA0p3vC8OE) and [ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/analysis/image-analyst/overview-of-image-classification.htm)). Of course, the ArcGIS approach will require an image or spatial analyst license and QGIS provides those tools for free.

The resulting unsupervised classification could be manual edited to finalize your classification thus saving you some heads-up digitizing time.